# Determine the shape of a quartic polynomial given its equation only.

Tags: polynomials, conic-sections, quartics

Some quartic (fourth-degree) polynomials resemble deformed parentheses, in that they only have one stationary point, which is their global maximum/minimum. This makes them share some properties of parentheses, such as the uniqueness of the slope of the tangent over their entire domain. Other quartic polynomials, however, have three stationary points, where one or two of them are global maxima/minima.

How do I predict whether the quartic polynomial will have a single turning point, given its equation only (and not by looking at its graph)?

Comment: Far as I know a quartic polynomial has three turning points determined by the behaviour at $\pm \infty$ that resembles the quadratic (both arms up or down).

Comment: @Windsoul Were are the 3 turning points for $y=x^4$ ?

Comment: 3 points at most, @JeanMarie. One point at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quartic polynomial (with real coefficients) $p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has a single turning point if its first derivative, $p'(x)=4x^3+3ax^2+2bx+c$, has only one real root (or three identical real roots, in the special case $a=b=c=0$). A cubic polynomial, in turn, has only one real root if its *discriminant* $\Delta$ is negative$^{(*)}$. For the cubic $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$, with $A\neq 0$, it has the following expression:
$$
\Delta=\frac{4(B^2-3AC)^3-(2B^3-9ABC+27A^2D)^2}{27A^2}.
$$
One can, therefore, determine whether a quartic polynomial has only a single turning point by computing the discriminant of its first derivative; the answer will be *yes* if $\Delta<0$.

---

$^{(*)}$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

Comment: That's very useful. Many thanks for your clear answer.